# Инициализация переменных в 16-ричной системе

Tags: c++

Можно ли иницилизировать переменную в 16-ричной системе исчисления?

```
 class Prac 
 {
 public:
 void foo() 
 {
    ++b;
 }

 private:
 static int b;
 };
 int Prac::b = 0x7FFF; //Можно ли инициализировать 16 числом и к какой ошибке это 
 может //привести.
 int main()
 {
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Можно. А почему бы вам самому это не проверить?

Comment: Проверил, эмм все работает, но мало ли , вдруг я незнаю каких то мелочей

Comment: Это мелочи вроде несовпадения типа переменной и константы, которой вы инициализируете (и/или их размера в памяти) о чем вам может сообщать компилятор при компиляции с разными ключами. Imho получаете на практике такое сообщение (warning) и по ходу дела правите. Хотя, может тут и найдутся любители много-писать и напишут исчерпывающую инструкцию на русском

Comment: [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)